# How do you insert rows into Postgresql 8.4 when one column is a variable value?

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

I want to insert records into the "books" table for every author in the "author" table.  In other words, if this represented the author table:

```
> 1 - "Herman Melville" 
> 2 - "Stephen King" 
> 3 - "Truman Capote"
```

...then, the insert would yield these results in the "book" table:

```
> 'Hello World' - 1
> 'Hello World' - 2
> 'Hello World' - 3
```

I have the following INSERT statement (it's actually a crude example, but it demonstrates the objective):

```
INSERT INTO books (title, author_id) VALUES ('Hello World', SELECT id FROM author);
```

Unfortunately, this fails and I'm uncertain how to get each of the "id" values from the "author" table.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not clear why you'd want to insert the same entry for each author, but you could use a SELECT as the source for your INSERT, like this:

```
INSERT INTO books (title, author_id)
    SELECT 'Hello World', id
    FROM author
```

Edit: for some more info, check the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-insert.html) for INSERT; as you can see, the source can be either DEFAULT VALUES, VALUES or a query.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this one:

```
INSERT INTO books (title, author_id) SELECT 'Hello World', id FROM author;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also surround your subselect with parentheses:

```
 INSERT INTO books (title, author_id) 
  VALUES ('Hello World',  (SELECT id FROM author WHERE...) );
```

This syntax might be easiest to understand, but the other syntax pointed by other commenters (without VALUES) is probably more clean : you just build out the fly the record you want to insert (with a SELECT) and then you INSERT it; it could also be more efficient if you had many subselects for distict fields.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO books (title, author_id) SELECT 'Hello World', id FROM author
```

Comment: Exact dupe of the one above it. Please consider removing the answer.

Comment: @Huuuze To be fair, the "one above" was posted afterwards, some 18 minutes afterwards. Let the community decide which one they like.

Comment: @Lasse Um, nope. After the down vote, it's two up -- they're posted at the exact same time. Look more closely next time.

Comment: Yeah, I missed which one you were talking about, the ordering here is random when things have the same amount of votes, so "above" and "below" is easy to get wrong. I see what you mean now. Sorry.